# Dell Latitude 3590 freeze after suspend Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, dell, freeze

I have **Dell Latitude 3950** with **Ubuntu 16.04**. My Problem is that whenever I resume it from the suspend my screen freezes and nothing happens. I have hard boot it.

I have even changed my kernel version from *`4.4.0-148-generic`* to *`4.13.14-041314-generic`* but it still freezes.

My system info

```
Linux SO-Latitude-3590 4.13.14-041314-generic #201711180632 SMP Sat Nov 18 11:34:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't want to break something while trying every change. Anyone has faced this issue before. Links regarding the possible solution would be appreciated. I can work on it please project me in the right direction. so that others could help. Thank you.